# Do I understand the Ito Integral right?

Tags: probability-theory, brownian-motion, stochastic-integrals

Hello I am new to Ito integrals. I know how the Ito integral is defined and that it is not defined by pathwise convergence but in $L^2$ instead.
But I think I actually did not quite get the point. How do I understand an expression like the following identity?

$$\int_0^t Bs \text{d}Bs = \frac{1}{2}B_t^2 - \frac{1}{2}t$$

Does it mean that for every $\omega$,

$$\Big(\int_0^t Bs \text{d}Bs\Big)(\omega) = \Big(\frac{1}{2}B_t^2 - \frac{1}{2}t \Big)(\omega) \text{ }?$$

In all my books the stochastic integrals are written without any $\omega$'s that's why I am asking where they would be...

Comment: Yes, almost surely $\omega$ since elements in $L^2$ are equal up to a null set. Btw you can write the RHS as $$\frac 1 2\left( B_t^2(\omega) - t\right) $$

Comment: That's all I wanted to know. Thanks! :)